ERROR Capacitor Mixed Content: insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
You will get this error if you try to do insecure GET requests to a server running on http, instead of https.

The solution is to update capacitor.config.ts or capacitor.config.json and add this line:
 "server": {
    "androidScheme": "http",
  },

